# IIS Exception logger for every app within

Tags: c#, exception, iis, iis-7, httpmodule

I have used Elmah ,log4net and nlog for logging exceptions.

I m curious how I can catch exceptions for any applications of websites that runs under same IIS.

Do i need to develop and IIS Module and bind it?

Not sure, how can i catch exceptions that happens in any apps within IIS?

I m interested in intercepting the exceptions and such to log myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tried but whats stopping you from adding elmah to machine config?

This solution should suitable for you check it
http://www.christiaanverwijs.nl/post/2012/06/27/NET-HttpModule-to-log-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-IIS-75-through-Log4NET-(globally-or-per-site).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via IIS configuration.   Check detailed description here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725786%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: well how can i intercept the exceptions and errors? so i can handle them myself.

Comment: @DarthVader, sorry didn't get you correctly.  For handling check this article - http://www.christiaanverwijs.nl/post/2012/06/27/NET-HttpModule-to-log-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-IIS-75-through-Log4NET-%28globally-or-per-site%29.aspx